# Assign the same Drive Letter Every Time to USB Drive with USBDLM

Tags: usb-drive

I try to use USBDLM to connect separately a USB sticks and a USB drive to appear always as drive T.

On every USB stich/drive I put a USBDLM.ini with:

```
[DriveLetters]
    Letters=%drive%\usbdlm.ini
```

and for every drive its own configuration as:

```
[DriveLetters10]
    ; Aldistick
    DeviceID1=USB 2.0 Flash  Disk USB Device
    Letter1=T

; many other options are documented in the Help files

[DriveLetters20]
VolumeSerial=16ED-33C5
Letter=T
```

But I find out that this is not working unless I put the same usbdlm.ini file for every stick/drive into the folder where USBDLM.exe is placed.

Do I something wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the drive you need an USBDLM.INI which contains a simple [DriveLetters] section with the desired letters:

```
[DriveLetters]
Letters=T
```

In the main USBDLM.INI you let is read the letter from the INI on the drive:

```
[DriveLetters]
Letters=%drive%\usbdlm.ini
```

Maybe it is more handy to let USBDLM extract the desired drive letter from the volume label, e.g. label it "Drive T" and write in the main USBDLM.INI:

```
[DriveLetters]
Letters=%LetterFromLabel%
```

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#by_label

Uwe Sieber